# Expired client secret Azure

Tags: azure, azure-app-registration

Is it possible to determine which resource (API, app service, application) is using an expired client secret? The app registration to which the expired client secret belongs has multiple valid client secrets, but I don't know which resource is using the expired client secret.

I tried to manually look into logic apps. into the keyvault etc.

Comment: Not a very efficient way but a workaround- Go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Sign-ins.
Look for failed sign-in attempts and check their details. You might be able to correlate the timing of these failures with the expiration of the client secret. If the resources are sending diagnostic data to Azure Monitor or Log Analytics, you could query the logs for errors related to authentication. Look for errors that indicate an issue with the client secret.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, to determine which resource is using an expired client secret, you can check the Azure AD sign-in logs to see which applications are failing to authenticate. You can also check the Azure AD audit logs to see which applications are using the expired client secret.

1. Go to the Azure portal and navigate to Azure Active Directory.
2. Click on "Sign-ins" under the "Monitoring" section.
3. Filter the logs by failure.
4. Look for sign-in failures related to the expired client secret.

[image]

[image]

same way for audit log-

[image]

*Additionally, you can use azure log analytics to query your requirement*

To search for the expired client secret issue, you will want to look for failed sign-ins related to the service principal (application). Here's a query that should help you identify failed sign-ins potentially due to an expired client secret:

```
SigninLogs
| where ResultType != 0 // here 0 is a successful sign-in
| where AppId == "<App Registration Application (client) ID>" // replace with your actual application ID
| project TimeGenerated, AppDisplayName, AppId, ResultDescription, ResultType, CorrelationId, IPAddress, Location
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
```

This query will list the failed sign-in attempts for the application specified by the `<App Registration Application (client) ID>`. Be sure to replace `<App Registration Application (client) ID>` with your actual Application ID.

or you don't even have to go that critical and simply use

```
SigninLogs
| where Status contains "Failure"
```

and then export it as excel and filter out with failure reason.
[image]

The `ResultType` field is used here to filter out successful sign-ins; typically, `0` indicates success, so any non-zero `ResultType` could indicate a failure, which might be due to the expired client secret. `ResultDescription` should give you more information about why the sign-in attempt failed.